# Universal App Interop Dll and content files

Tags: c#, dll, uwp, interop

I have a c++ dll named : `analysis.dll` and I already managed to wrap it using the `DllImport` attribute.

This Dll somehow loads a file named `analysis.sys` that contains a licence key.

I've added my two dll to my UWP project and set the following options:

- `analysis.dll`

  - Build Action : `Content`
  - Copy to output directory : `Copy if newer`
- `analysis.sys`

  - Build Action : `Content`
  - Copy to output directory : `Copy if newer`

The main problem, is that the `analysis.dll` is loaded and we can use the methods thanks to the wrapper (with `DllImport`), but this dll can't load the `analysis.sys` file.

I've done this test with a WPF application and it works perfectly...

Why it won't work with UWP ? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Your UWP package can only contain application code, not system code. It cannot deploy drivers to the user's system, as the installer needs to be able to run without elevation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The `analysis.sys` file is more like a text file with the licence key of the dll stored in it. Maybe the dll do something that needs previlege elevation ?

Comment: What is the exact point of failure and what's the error message/code? You said you can't load analysis.sys. How do you attempt to load it?

Comment: To be simple, the DLL needs the SYS file to work. Because the sys file contains the licence key. I assume that the DLL loads the SYS key because if you remove this file, my WPF test app doens't work anymore.
The point is, when my WPF test app has the two files, it works well. Remove the SYS file and it doesn't work anymore.
Tried the same on UWP and even with the SYS file it doesn't work.

Comment: How do you load the file? Deploying an reading a text file will work fine, but if this is done by deploying and running driver code it won't work in a UWP app by design.

Comment: The file should be loaded by the `analysis.dll` which is an unmanaged dll (forgot to tell that). I don't think it runs any driver code.

Comment: How does the DLL load the file? Can you share that code? That code may need to be changed to be compliant with UWP.

Comment: I don't have the source of the DLL. On the documentation, it's mentioned : The license file (analysis.SYS). This file will be used by analysis.DLL for licensing. analysis.SYS should be copied to the same location where analysis.DLL resides.
The error I get from the DLL is that the DLL didn't found the licence key.

Comment: You will need to contact the 3rd party library vendor and make sure they support their library for UWP development. It sounds like the DLL is making an assumption that is not true in the context of the UWP app container, and will require a code change on their part to support this.

Comment: I see. I will contact them in that case. Thank you for you answers.
So UWP doesn't behave the same way as WPF about local files?

Comment: You can definitely load local files from your UWP, but some of the details and policies are different in the UWP app container. Some APIs are not supported, some assumptions - for example about the current directory - may not be true, etc. It's all speculation since be don't know their code, but the bottom line is they need to test in the UWP context and make code adjustments to be compliant with the app container rules.